# How to list products of a category in prestashop

Tags: categories, prestashop, product

I would like to list product of a category once i've selected a category in my left quicklaunch.

Does someone know how to do that ?

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: In the file classes/Category.php you will find the method `getProducts()` . It's the one used to get the product from a category.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip ;) I'm looking forward to know a little more about prestashop :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **following function** to get all the products of the category.

```
$id_category = Tools::getValue('id_category');

$products = Product::getProducts(Context::getContext()->language->id, 0, 0, 'date_upd', 'ASC', $id_category, true);
```

**$products** is an **array** of products belong to the category.

**Note:** **id_category** should be the **default category** of the product.